# How to curve fit scattered data with mutiple curve pattern

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I've encountered a problem dealing with curve fitting.
I have a scattered dataset which is plotted in the graph. From the graph, it's easy to tell there are at least two lines.
How can I fit these two curves? Or in another way, what can I do to separate the dataset to get two different datasets to fit curves?

Scattered data example:
[image: img]

Comment: This isn't really a programming question in my opinon. Consider asking on the mathematics site

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I thought it may be related to data clustering?

Comment: It seems like you are looking for a methodology or algorithm for this. This is essentially unrelated to programming and someone on mathematics will likely be able to help you better. Once you figure out what you need to do, if you need help implementing that in Python you can come back to stack overflow

Comment: Another option is https://stats.stackexchange.com/ Agree that it does not appear to be a programming problem.

Comment: many thanks to user1558604 and Michelle

Comment: I suggest you have a look [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html)

Comment: @mikuszefski Thanks for your comment. Actually I have just read some algorithm such as DBSCAN, still on the way trying to figure out how to implement the clustering.